# "Npm list" doesn't show any unmet dependencies, so why does my server error out?

Tags: node.js, npm

"npm list" returns this, in which there are no "unmet"s. But when I restart my server, it errors out and the error logs show "Error: Cannot find module 'async/each'" and other similar errors. I have been going through and installing each unfound module individually, but that is very tedious. What should I be doing instead?

EDIT: Also, doing "npm prune" doesn't seem to do anything ("npm list" still gives a lot of ERR-extraneous type things.)

EDIT 2: It's not a very sophisticated server, it's just meant to serve an HTML file and connect to a MongoDB. So the basic dependencies are Express, Socket.io, and MongoDB.

```
/home/djg/build
├── buffer-shims@1.0.0
├─┬ debug@4.2.0
│ └── ms@2.1.2 extraneous
├── engine.io-parser@4.0.1
├── es6-promise@3.2.1
├─┬ express@4.17.1
│ ├─┬ accepts@1.3.7
│ │ ├─┬ mime-types@2.1.27
│ │ │ └── mime-db@1.44.0
│ │ └── negotiator@0.6.2
│ ├── array-flatten@1.1.1
│ ├─┬ body-parser@1.19.0
│ │ ├── bytes@3.1.0
│ │ ├── content-type@1.0.4 deduped
│ │ ├── debug@2.6.9 extraneous
│ │ ├── depd@1.1.2 deduped
│ │ ├─┬ http-errors@1.7.2
│ │ │ ├── depd@1.1.2 deduped
│ │ │ ├── inherits@2.0.3
│ │ │ ├── setprototypeof@1.1.1 deduped
│ │ │ ├── statuses@1.5.0 deduped
│ │ │ └── toidentifier@1.0.0
│ │ ├─┬ iconv-lite@0.4.24
│ │ │ └── safer-buffer@2.1.2
│ │ ├── on-finished@2.3.0 deduped
│ │ ├── qs@6.7.0 deduped
│ │ ├─┬ raw-body@2.4.0
│ │ │ ├── bytes@3.1.0 deduped
│ │ │ ├── http-errors@1.7.2 deduped
│ │ │ ├── iconv-lite@0.4.24 deduped
│ │ │ └── unpipe@1.0.0 deduped
│ │ └── type-is@1.6.18 deduped
│ ├─┬ content-disposition@0.5.3
│ │ └── safe-buffer@5.1.2 deduped
│ ├── content-type@1.0.4
│ ├── cookie@0.4.0
│ ├── cookie-signature@1.0.6
│ ├── debug@2.6.9 extraneous
│ ├── depd@1.1.2
│ ├── encodeurl@1.0.2
│ ├── escape-html@1.0.3
│ ├── etag@1.8.1
│ ├─┬ finalhandler@1.1.2
│ │ ├── debug@2.6.9 extraneous
│ │ ├── encodeurl@1.0.2 deduped
│ │ ├── escape-html@1.0.3 deduped
│ │ ├── on-finished@2.3.0 deduped
│ │ ├── parseurl@1.3.3 deduped
│ │ ├── statuses@1.5.0 deduped
│ │ └── unpipe@1.0.0
│ ├── fresh@0.5.2
│ ├── merge-descriptors@1.0.1
│ ├── methods@1.1.2
│ ├─┬ on-finished@2.3.0
│ │ └── ee-first@1.1.1
│ ├── parseurl@1.3.3
│ ├── path-to-regexp@0.1.7
│ ├─┬ proxy-addr@2.0.6
│ │ ├── forwarded@0.1.2
│ │ └── ipaddr.js@1.9.1
│ ├── qs@6.7.0
│ ├── range-parser@1.2.1
│ ├── safe-buffer@5.1.2
│ ├─┬ send@0.17.1
│ │ ├── debug@2.6.9 extraneous
│ │ ├── depd@1.1.2 deduped
│ │ ├── destroy@1.0.4
│ │ ├── encodeurl@1.0.2 deduped
│ │ ├── escape-html@1.0.3 deduped
│ │ ├── etag@1.8.1 deduped
│ │ ├── fresh@0.5.2 deduped
│ │ ├── http-errors@1.7.2 deduped
│ │ ├── mime@1.6.0
│ │ ├── ms@2.1.1 extraneous
│ │ ├── on-finished@2.3.0 deduped
│ │ ├── range-parser@1.2.1 deduped
│ │ └── statuses@1.5.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ serve-static@1.14.1
│ │ ├── encodeurl@1.0.2 deduped
│ │ ├── escape-html@1.0.3 deduped
│ │ ├── parseurl@1.3.3 deduped
│ │ └── send@0.17.1 deduped
│ ├── setprototypeof@1.1.1
│ ├── statuses@1.5.0
│ ├─┬ type-is@1.6.18
│ │ ├── media-typer@0.3.0
│ │ └── mime-types@2.1.27 deduped
│ ├── utils-merge@1.0.1
│ └── vary@1.1.2
├─┬ has-binary@0.1.7
│ └── isarray@0.0.1 extraneous
├── json3@3.3.3
├─┬ mongodb@3.6.2
│ ├─┬ bl@2.2.1
│ │ ├─┬ readable-stream@2.3.7
│ │ │ ├── core-util-is@1.0.2
│ │ │ ├── inherits@2.0.3 deduped
│ │ │ ├── isarray@1.0.0 extraneous
│ │ │ ├── process-nextick-args@2.0.1
│ │ │ ├── safe-buffer@5.1.2 deduped
│ │ │ ├─┬ string_decoder@1.1.1
│ │ │ │ └── safe-buffer@5.1.2 deduped
│ │ │ └── util-deprecate@1.0.2
│ │ └── safe-buffer@5.1.2 deduped
│ ├── bson@1.1.5
│ ├── denque@1.4.1
│ ├─┬ require_optional@1.0.1
│ │ ├── resolve-from@2.0.0
│ │ └── semver@5.7.1
│ ├── safe-buffer@5.1.2 deduped
│ └─┬ saslprep@1.0.3
│   └─┬ sparse-bitfield@3.0.3
│     └── memory-pager@1.5.0
├─┬ mongodb-core@2.1.20
│ ├── bson@1.0.9 extraneous
│ └── require_optional@1.0.1 deduped
├─┬ mongoose@5.10.8
│ ├── bson@1.1.5 deduped
│ ├── kareem@2.3.1
│ ├── mongodb@3.6.2 extraneous
│ ├── mongoose-legacy-pluralize@1.0.2
│ ├── mpath@0.7.0
│ ├─┬ mquery@3.2.2
│ │ ├── bluebird@3.5.1
│ │ ├── debug@3.1.0 extraneous
│ │ ├── regexp-clone@1.0.0 deduped
│ │ ├── safe-buffer@5.1.2 deduped
│ │ └── sliced@1.0.1 deduped
│ ├── ms@2.1.2 extraneous
│ ├── regexp-clone@1.0.0
│ ├── safe-buffer@5.2.1 extraneous
│ ├── sift@7.0.1
│ └── sliced@1.0.1
├── options@0.0.6
├─┬ parsejson@0.0.3
│ └─┬ better-assert@1.0.2
│   └── callsite@1.0.0
├─┬ socket.io@2.3.0
│ ├── debug@4.1.1 extraneous
│ ├─┬ engine.io@3.4.2
│ │ ├── accepts@1.3.7 deduped
│ │ ├── base64id@2.0.0
│ │ ├── cookie@0.3.1 extraneous
│ │ ├── debug@4.1.1 extraneous
│ │ ├── engine.io-parser@2.2.1 extraneous
│ │ └── ws@7.3.1
│ ├─┬ has-binary2@1.0.3
│ │ └── isarray@2.0.1
│ ├── socket.io-adapter@1.1.2
│ ├─┬ socket.io-client@2.3.0
│ │ ├── backo2@1.0.2
│ │ ├── base64-arraybuffer@0.1.5 extraneous
│ │ ├── component-bind@1.0.0
│ │ ├── component-emitter@1.2.1
│ │ ├── debug@4.1.1 extraneous
│ │ ├─┬ engine.io-client@3.4.4
│ │ │ ├── component-emitter@1.3.0 extraneous
│ │ │ ├── component-inherit@0.0.3
│ │ │ ├── debug@3.1.0 extraneous
│ │ │ ├── engine.io-parser@2.2.1 extraneous
│ │ │ ├── has-cors@1.1.0 deduped
│ │ │ ├── indexof@0.0.1 deduped
│ │ │ ├── parseqs@0.0.6 extraneous
│ │ │ ├── parseuri@0.0.6 extraneous
│ │ │ ├── ws@6.1.4 extraneous
│ │ │ ├── xmlhttprequest-ssl@1.5.5
│ │ │ └── yeast@0.1.2
│ │ ├── has-binary2@1.0.3 deduped
│ │ ├── has-cors@1.1.0
│ │ ├── indexof@0.0.1
│ │ ├── object-component@0.0.3
│ │ ├─┬ parseqs@0.0.5
│ │ │ └── better-assert@1.0.2 deduped
│ │ ├─┬ parseuri@0.0.5
│ │ │ └── better-assert@1.0.2 deduped
│ │ ├── socket.io-parser@3.3.1 extraneous
│ │ └── to-array@0.1.4
│ └─┬ socket.io-parser@3.4.1
│   ├── component-emitter@1.2.1 deduped
│   ├── debug@4.1.1 extraneous
│   └── isarray@2.0.1 deduped
└── ultron@1.1.1

npm ERR! extraneous: ms@2.1.2 /home/djg/build/node_modules/debug/node_modules/ms
npm ERR! extraneous: debug@2.6.9 /home/djg/build/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/debug
npm ERR! extraneous: debug@2.6.9 /home/djg/build/node_modules/express/node_modules/debug
npm ERR! extraneous: debug@2.6.9 /home/djg/build/node_modules/finalhandler/node_modules/debug
npm ERR! extraneous: debug@2.6.9 /home/djg/build/node_modules/send/node_modules/debug
npm ERR! extraneous: ms@2.1.1 /home/djg/build/node_modules/send/node_modules/ms
npm ERR! extraneous: isarray@0.0.1 /home/djg/build/node_modules/has-binary/node_modules/isarray
npm ERR! extraneous: isarray@1.0.0 /home/djg/build/node_modules/readable-stream/node_modules/isarray
npm ERR! extraneous: bson@1.0.9 /home/djg/build/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson
npm ERR! extraneous: mongodb@3.6.2 /home/djg/build/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb
npm ERR! extraneous: ms@2.1.2 /home/djg/build/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/ms
npm ERR! extraneous: safe-buffer@5.2.1 /home/djg/build/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/safe-buffer
npm ERR! extraneous: debug@3.1.0 /home/djg/build/node_modules/mquery/node_modules/debug
npm ERR! extraneous: cookie@0.3.1 /home/djg/build/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/cookie
npm ERR! extraneous: debug@4.1.1 /home/djg/build/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/debug
npm ERR! extraneous: engine.io-parser@2.2.1 /home/djg/build/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/engine.io-parser
npm ERR! extraneous: component-emitter@1.3.0 /home/djg/build/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/component-emitter
npm ERR! extraneous: debug@3.1.0 /home/djg/build/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/debug
npm ERR! extraneous: engine.io-parser@2.2.1 /home/djg/build/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-parser
npm ERR! extraneous: parseqs@0.0.6 /home/djg/build/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/parseqs
npm ERR! extraneous: parseuri@0.0.6 /home/djg/build/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/parseuri
npm ERR! extraneous: ws@6.1.4 /home/djg/build/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws
npm ERR! extraneous: base64-arraybuffer@0.1.5 /home/djg/build/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/base64-arraybuffer
npm ERR! extraneous: debug@4.1.1 /home/djg/build/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/debug
npm ERR! extraneous: socket.io-parser@3.3.1 /home/djg/build/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/socket.io-parser
npm ERR! extraneous: debug@4.1.1 /home/djg/build/node_modules/socket.io-parser/node_modules/debug
npm ERR! extraneous: debug@4.1.1 /home/djg/build/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/debug
```

EDIT 2:
Here is my server.js file:

```
var express = require('express') //Require express for middleware use
const app = express()
var http = require('http').createServer(app)
var io = require('socket.io')(http) //IO is the server

var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var assert = require('assert')
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.set('debug', true)

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test'

//BASICS
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/served")) //Serve static files

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile('./index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  // socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    // io.emit('chat message', msg);
  // });
  console.log("A user connected: ", socket.id)
});

http.listen(8080, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:8080');
});

//HANDLE USER LOGIN:
app.use(bodyParser.json())       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded()) // to support URL-encoded bodies

mongoose.connect(url)
var db = mongoose.connection
db.on('error', console.error)
var User
db.once('open', function() {
  var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    level: Number,
    onePoRank: Number,
    twoPoRank: Number,
    type: String,
    tutDone: Boolean
  })

  // userSchema.statics.findOne = function(id, callback){
  //   return this.findOne({ _id: new RegExp(id, 'i') }, callback);
  // }

  User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)

  // db.close()
})

app.post('/menu', function(req, res){ // Save new user or load existing one, and send that data back to the client.
  var username = req.param('username')
  console.log('username "'+username+'" parsed from form')

  //check the database for a user with that name:
  User.findOne({username: username}, function(err, user){
    if (err) {console.log("The user search caused an error")}
    if (user === null) {
      console.log("No user by name %s found--creating new user", username)
      var newUser = new User({username: username, level:0, onePoRank:0, twoPoRank: 0, type: 'human'})
      newUser.save(function (err, newUser) { //Add the new user to the database
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log("New user %s saved to database", username)
        res.json(newUser)
      })
    } else { //User was found in the database
      console.log("User %s found.", username)
      res.json(user)
    }
  })

  db.once('close', function(){console.log("database closed.")})
  // res.sendFile('./menu.html', {root: __dirname+"/served"})
});

app.post('/user', function(req, res){ // Update the user in the database:
  var what = req.param('what')
  var username = req.param('user').username
  // var username = req.param('username')
  // console.log('username "'+username+'" parsed from form')

  User.findOne({username: username}, function(err, user){
    if (err) {console.log("The user search caused an error")}
    if (user === null) {
      console.log("No user by name %s found. That was unexpected.", username)
    } else {
      console.log("User %s found. Updating.", username)
      user[what] = req.param('user')[what]
      user.save(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log('User successfully updated!')
      });
    }
  })

  res.json({'a':0}) //just to prevent an empty response error
});
```

Comment: Presumably, given the number of extraneous dependencies, because your package.json doesn't match what your code actually needs, but without a [mre] it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: I added my server.js file, hopefully that is enough, if not let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, I deleted the "node_modules" folder in my build folder, did "npm install [module] --save" for each of the packages found in require statements in my server.js file, wiped my server clean and resynced my build files to it, then did "npm install" on the server.